# Set Global value based on Array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array as following and trying to loop it and assign a global value based on array values.

```
var arrayData = [3, 5, 8, 11, 18, 20, 24, 25]
```

When page is loading, I assigned "a" value should be 3 and "b" value should be 5. They are  `0th and 1st elements`

of the array.

After 5 seconds(b value) the page loaded, "a" value should be changed to 8(`arrayData[2]`) and "b" value should be changed to 10(`arrayData[3]`). Similarly, after 11 seconds(b value) that page loaded, "a" value should be changed to 18(`arrayData[4]`) and "b" value should be changed to 20(`arrayData[5]`).

For this I am trying the following setInterval function code,

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

            var arrayData = [3, 5, 8, 11, 18, 20, 24, 25]
            var a = arrayData[0];
            var b = arrayData[1]

            window.setInterval(function(){
                console.log("B val : "+b+ " A val : "+a)
                if(((new Date().getTime() / 1000)- seconds) >= b) {
                    for (var i = 2; i < arrayData.length; i+=2){
                        a = arrayData[i];
                        b = arrayData[i+1];             
                    }                   
               }
             }, 100);

        </script>
```

But "a" values is assigned initially 3 and then 24 only. Not with other odd elements. also "b" value is assigned with 5 and 25 only.

my log shows as follows,

```
    B val : 5 A val : 3
    B val : 5 A val : 3
    B val : 5 A val : 3
    B val : 5 A val : 3
    B val : 5 A val : 3
    B val : 25 A val : 24
    B val : 25 A val : 24
    B val : 25 A val : 24
    B val : 25 A val : 24
    B val : 25 A val : 24
```

Can anyone assist in this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.shift` function. (try on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf0wxess/))

```
var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var arrayData = [3, 5, 8, 11, 18, 20, 24, 25];
var a = arrayData.shift();
var b = arrayData.shift();

window.setInterval(function() {
  console.log("B val : " + b + " A val : " + a)
  if(((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - seconds) >= b) {
    a = arrayData.shift();
    b = arrayData.shift();
    seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: i'm not sure that's what he's trying to do.. if it is, where did the 10 come from in his example...

Comment: @RobertParham I think he made a typo because `arrayData[3] === 11` and not `10`.

Answer (score 0):

the if statement

```
if(((new Date().getTime() / 1000)- seconds) >= b)
```

only be true after about 5 seconds(*the initial value of b*), so at the first 5 seconds your `a` and `b` keep the same; however, once that `if` statement get true, your `a` and `b` will change inside the `for` statement; and, finally, they become to `24` and `25` each.

Answer (score 0):

You might do like this; (I just do 100ms instead of 1000ms for the sake of faster demo)

```js
var  a,b,
arrayData = [3, 5, 8, 11, 18, 20, 24, 25];

function updateGlobals(arr){
  a = arr[0] || a;
  b = arr[1] || b;
  arr.length >= 2 && setTimeout(updateGlobals,arr[1]*100,arr.slice(2));
  console.log(a,b);
}

updateGlobals(arrayData);
```